# How to get shutter glasses to work with WebGL on Linux

Tags: webgl

Is there any generic way to enable frame-sequential stereo with WebGL content?
(I'm not talking about hard-coding this into the presentation/game.)

I can use shutter glasses with anything that can display two images in sync with the monitor's refresh rate. (Bino, Blender Game Engine) These applications use standard OpenGL quadbuffering.

How would one go about getting stereo to work with stuff like let's say the fish tank demo?

I understand on Windows one can emulate WebGL in DirectX and somehow force stereoscopy that way. I'm a casual Linux user therefore have no access to this. There should't be a need for us to hack things like that get stereo.

Would it be even **possible** to write let's say an add-on for Firefox that hijacks the camera in any WebGL scene to enable this functionality?

Comment: For your last question if it would be possible to write a plugin that works with _every_ WebGL app. Its probably not since the *camera* is just a matrix like many others in a typical 3d application. One could however target common frameworks like Three.js